# Freezing conv layers in pre trained VGG16 model

Tags: pytorch, computer-vision

```
model_conv = torchvision.models.vgg16(pretrained=True)
for param in model_conv.parameters():
    param.requires_grad = False
model_conv.classifier.requires_grad_=True
model_conv.classifier[6].out_features=len(class_names)

model_conv = model_conv.to(device)

criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

optimizer_conv = optim.SGD(model_conv.classifier.parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0.9)

exp_lr_scheduler = lr_scheduler.StepLR(optimizer_conv, step_size=7, gamma=0.1)
```

Here in the VGG16 model, I want to train the classifier layer on my images and freeze the convolution layers. I am getting the same error.

```
RuntimeError: element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn
```

Comment: Be mindful of giving feedback to answers, this is the fourth time I am answering one of your questions without receiving any response whatsoever (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69222705/use-of-dim-0-1-in-pytorch-and-nn-softmax), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69393281/freezing-conv-layers-in-pre-trained-vgg16-model), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69220221/use-of-torch-stack), and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68542593/runtimeerror-mat1-and-mat2-shapes-cannot-be-multiplied-28x28-and-784x64)...).

Comment: Sorry mate, I will now remind myself to respond to the answers. I generally forget to mark them as solutions.Will do from now on.

Answer (score 0):

**First** of all `requires_grad_` is an inplace function, not an attribute you can either do:

```
>>> model_conv.classifier.requires_grad_(True)
```

Or modify the `requires_grad` attribute directly (as you did in the *for* loop):

```
>>> model_conv.classifier.requires_grad = True
```

**Second**, you can't change the number of neurons in the layer by overwriting `out_features`. This attribute just contains the number of neurons and as no effect on the underlying content of the layer. You need to overwrite the layer with a newly initialized layer. For example:

```
>>> classifier = model_conv.classifier[6]
>>> model_conv.classifier[6] = nn.Linear(classifier.in_features, class_names)
```

---

A minimal example would be:

```
model_conv = torchvision.models.vgg16(pretrained=True).requires_grad_(False)
clf = model_conv.classifier[6]
clf.out_features=nn.Linear(clf.in_features, len(class_names))

optimizer_conv = optim.SGD(model_conv.classifier.parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0.9)
x = torch.rand(1,3,100,100, requires_grad=True)
model_conv(x).mean().backward()
optimizer_conv.step()
```